# Reading just parts of buffers in a fifo (VecDeque)

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a

`packets: VecDeque<Packet>`

which is a **fifo** for tcp packets. That is, a client reads from this deque everytime, gets the oldest buffer, and fills a buffer, like this:

```
fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        buf.put_slice(self.packets.front().unwrap().internal_slice)
}
```

there's a problem here. If `buf`'s capacity is smaller than `internal_slice`, it panics. So we cannot simply rely on getting the `front()` everytime. What would be the best way to consume part of the `VecDeque`'s oldest buffer?

I thought of getting the front, and if the buffer is too big, only copy part of it and then put it back and update something internally on `Packet`, but is there a better and less error prone way of doing this? Also not needing to copy and put it back, which would copy the buffer too many times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bytes::Bytes` in the Packet. The your code could look something like this:

```rust
// imports for bytes
use bytes::{Bytes, Buf};

fn poll_read(
    self: Pin<&mut Self>,
    cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {

    let front_packet = match self.packets.front_mut() {
        Some(p) => p,
        None => return Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    };
    let bytes = &mut front_packet.bytes;

    // the len that can be written
    let len = buf.remaining()
        .min(bytes.len());

    buf.put_slice(&bytes[..len]);
    bytes.advance(len);

    if bytes.is_empty() {
        // bytes is empty because we could write everything
        let _ = self.packets.pop_front();
    }

     Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
}
```

With this code you copy every part of the packet exactly once.
I personally would say, it's quite easy to reason about this code and determine if it contains errors or not.

If you don't wan't to use `bytes::Bytes` you could use a `Cursor<Box<[u8]>>`:

```rust
// imports for cursor
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, BufRead};

fn poll_read(
    self: Pin<&mut Self>,
    cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {

    let front_packet = match self.packets.front_mut() {
        Some(p) => p,
        None => return Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    };
    // bytes is of type Cursor<Box<[u8]>>
    let bytes = &mut front_packet.bytes;
    let slice = bytes.fill_buf().unwrap();
    // same as bytes.get_ref()[bytes.position()..]

    // the len that can be written
    let len = buf.remaining()
        .min(slice.len());

    buf.put_slice(&slice[..len]);
    bytes.consume(len);
    let slice = &slice[len..];

    if slice.is_empty() {
        // slice is empty because we could write everything
        let _ = self.packets.pop_front();
    }

     Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
}
```

### Documentation

- [std::io::Cursor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html)
- [bytes::Bytes](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/struct.Bytes.html)